# JSON Formatting on SharePoint List column to enable cascading dropdown

Tags: json, sharepoint, cascadingdropdown, sharepoint-list

Been working on some sample code to format a list column B based on value of list column A.

I have 2 lists:
List A - This list are the main list for data entry. Columns are Item, Region and Country.
List B - This list contains 2 columns; Region and Country.

What I want to do is, based on user selection, only display Country corresponding to the selection Region. All Countries/Regions are maintained in List B.

So far I've tried:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "display": "inline-block",
    "padding": "10px 0 10px 0",
    "min-height": "auto"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 10px 0 0"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Folder"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "Show Countries",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_top",
        "href": {
          "operator": "+",
          "operands": [
            "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/AllItems.aspx?ID=",
            "@currentField.lookupValue",
            "[$Title]",
            "&FilterType1=Lookup"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This obviously is not the correct solution, but being very new to JSON this is the best I could do by referencing msdn docs. The link works properly, although it's not needed for the final solution. Basically, I only want the user to see Country based on Region selection. I'm therefore missing the result as to display the lookup value rather than "Show countries".

Any help or pointers towards further help/documentation are greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, the JSON formatting does not support create cascading dropdown on SharePoint Online.

You can use SP service (JS) to create cascading drop-down list.

**Reference:**

- [How to create Cascading Drop Down list in SharePoint
  Online/2016/2013/2010 - Using SP Services (JS )](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcTI_UQ55TM)

Comment: Thank you. Ended up with creating a power app custom form. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this requirements in SharePoint online.

1. Using JSON formatting:

   You can build cascading drop down fields using `inlineEditField` in JSON and save values to list columns with the help of `setValue` action.

   Refer this link for example JSON: [Dependent-DropDown](https://github.com/Fedes365/Microsoft-Lists-Templates/tree/main/Dependent-DropDown)

   [image]

You can take the JSON from above reference and adjust as per your requirements.

**Note**: In your JSON, you have to use the correct **internal names** of your columns. You can get the internal name of your list/library columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

---

2. Using Power Apps (If you want to use list forms):

   You can use Power apps to customize the list form and develop cascading drop downs with the help of functions/formula.

   Check below links for detailed information and tutorial:

   1. [Create dependent drop-down lists in a canvas app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/dependent-drop-down-lists)
   2. [Working with Cascading Lists in SharePoint and Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/working-with-cascading-lists-in-sharepoint-and-powerapps)

   [image]